# How to display search results in an overlapping/dropdown style

Tags: html, css, autosuggest, searchbar, search-suggestion

Hi I have a website with a search function and I would like to have the results displayed like the google search, so that the results show directly below the search bar. The screenshot shows the idea:
[image]

My the html for my search bar looks as follows:

```
<form class="user-search-form form-inline" action="{% url 'user-search' %}" method="POST">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
                            </div>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input id="user_search" type="text" name="input" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group" id="results">
                            {% include 'feed/user_search.html' %}
                        </ul>
                    </form>
```

Right now my results are displayed within the navbar which is not looking very good imo.
How can I have it like in the google search? (Does not have to be an exact clone but something like that :D)

Comment: did you try this? `.list-group{display:flex; flex-direction:column;}`

Comment: Use datalist and then customise it. Check the w3schools for syntax implementation